# Python unidecode generating extra \n

Tags: python, string, unicode, line-breaks

I am using the following code to remove accentuation from string.
The input (inp) is a file with string with accentuation on it.
The output (outp)is a file.

The code is as follows:

```
49 def remove_unidecode(inp, outp):
50     ''' Remove accent and special characters
51     + lower case '''
52     print "# remove accents"
53     for line in inp:
54         uline = unicode(line, 'utf-8')
55         udline = unidecode(uline)
56         outp.write(udline.lower())
57     outp.close()
```

The problem is that the unidecode is creating extra \n, i.e., print extra line breaks:

```
$ wc -l *
3619 inp.txt
3879 outp.txt
```

Does anyone knows why it is happening?

Comment: I changed line 56 to: outp.write(udline.rstrip('\n').lower()), but the error continues.

Comment: I think we'd need to see `unidecode` to tell you what's going wrong here.

Comment: How are the files being opened? If the input file is opened in binary mode and output in text mode that would double up the the newlines if the input has \r\n line endings. They would change to \r\n\n.

Comment: Here is unidecode: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: Files are open like that: `inp = open(path_inp, 'r')` and `outp = open(path_out, 'w')`.